# weighted curve fitting with lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab

I wanted to fit an  arbitrary function to my data set. Therefore, I used `lsqcurvefit` in MATLAB. Now I want to give weight to the fit procedure, meaning when curve fitting function (`lsqcurvefit`) is calculating the residue of the fit, some data point are more important than the others. To be more specific I want to use statistical weighting method.

```
w=1/y(x),
```

where `w` is a matrix contains the weight of each data point and `y` is the data set.

I cannot find anyway to make weighted curve fitting with `lsqcurvefit`. Is there any trick I should follow or is there any other function rather than `lsqcurvefit` which do it for me?

Comment: if you are dealing with linear least squares you can do this from scratch using a vandermonde and weight matrix.

Comment: @mathematician1975, thanks but It'a not the case. I have a non-linear function which should fit to the dataset.

Comment: What does your cost function look like? Can you not get the weighting in there?

Comment: @Dan, I have no idea how to get the weighting in the function.



it is like a lorentzian function with a pick near the corner frequency. It can be called as yellow noise ([link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22182046)). It is a complicate function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For doing weighting, I find it much easier to use [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) which is the function that `lsqcurvefit` calls to do the actual fitting.

You first have to define a function that you are trying to minimize, ie. a cost function. You need to pass in your weighting function as an [extra parameter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) to your function as a vector:

```
x = yourIndependentVariable;
y = yourData;
weightVector = sqrt(abs(1./y));
costFunction = @(A) weightVector.*(yourModelFunction(A) - y);

aFit = lsqnonlin(costFunction,aGuess);
```

The reason for the square root in the weighting function definition is that `lsqnonlin` requires the residuals, not the squared residuals or their sum, so you need to pre-unsquare the weights.

Alternatively, if you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use `nlinfit` which will accept a weighting vector/matrix as one of the optional inputs.