# Weighted fitting when independent variables have different weights (non-linear)

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I came across this question and it is obvious to me. If I have 3 variables and they have different weights, how do I use it with lsqnonlin?

[weighted curve fitting with lsqcurvefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043739/weighted-curve-fitting-with-lsqcurvefit)

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
Assuming you have a weight matrix `W` (which can be a sparse diagonal matrix), and the nonlinear fitting function `F`, then the fitting function using lambda-expression and premultiply the measurement data `ydata` with the Cholesky factor `R` as given below.

```
R = chol( W, 'upper');
F_w = @(x, xdata) R * F( x, xdata);
ydata_w = R * ydata;
x_w = lsqcurvefit(F_w, x0, xdata, ydata_w)
```